# I have written multiple classes inside MY_Model.php as I needed more than one base class(to be extended by different subclass models)

Tags: php, codeigniter

For example I have the following subclasses in MY_Model.php(in core folder of codeigniter)

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    //some methods common to all users
}

class user1_user2_common_model extends MY_Model //extended by only user1 & user2 subclasses
{
    //methods of this class are used by only user1 and user2
}

class user2_user3_common_model extends MY_Model //extended by only user2 & user3 subclasses
{ 
    //methods of this class are only used by user2 and user3
}
```

**This is working fine.Only thing I need to know is whether this is an acceptable approach.If not how to enable above type of inheritance in codeigniter**

Comment: What is the point of `MY_Model` it adds nothing to the base class `CI_Model` `My_Model` should be used to add base class functionallity that is not provided by `CI_Model`

Comment: The other 2 classes should be written as 2 seperate files and as far as I can see they could extent `CI_Model` in the normal way

Comment: There was discussion on CI forums about this and one opinion (I think of one of admins jlp) was to use multiple classes in one file. Although I like to have it sorted in mutliple files.

Comment: Well I have edited my code given in the question to make it more clear.Now @RiggsFolly suggested to have two separate files but I want to use inheritance and inheritance only seems to work(atleast in my project),when I put the base classes in MY_Model.php.I have also tried to create something like MY_user1_user2_common_model(extending CI_Model) and put it in core folder, but inheritance does not work when another class tries to extend it.It works only when I put all the classes in MY_Model.php.Any suggestions.Also I read about hooks but as I am a total newbie I think it will hard for me